# Deterministic algorithms for computational distance between distributions

Tags: algorithms, probability-theory

Computational distance between sequences of distributions $\{X_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\{Y_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ can be defined as the maximum, over all probabilistic polynomial time algorithms $A$, of
$$ \left|\underset{x \sim X_{n}}{\mathsf{Pr}}(A(x) = 1) - \underset{x \sim Y_{n}}{\mathsf{Pr}}(A(x) = 1)\right|, $$

for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We can, very similarly, define computational indistinguishability to be when the computational distance is a negligible function of $n$. Here is my question: can we use a deterministic polynomial-time algorithm in place of a probabilistic one without loss of generality? Can we say that the maximum computational distance is achieved by a deterministic algorithm? Will this algorithm be non-uniform?

Comment: Does the following help? Every randomized algorithm is a distribution over deterministic algorithms.

Comment: Yes, I think it helps. Just for a quick sanity check, the answers are: yes, we can use a deterministic-polynomial time algorithm without losing generality; the maximum is achieved by one such algorithm; the algorithm will be non-uniform (a particular sequence of the random bits need to be hard-coded in the input); right?

Comment: Can we have deterministic algorithms that have other forms of non-uniformity, without loss of generality in the definition? For example, the ability to sample from either $X_{n}$ or $Y_{n}$ (ie, the algorithm will be deterministic given the samples)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

> Every randomized algorithm $A(x)$ can be expressed as a deterministic algorithm $A(x;r)$ where $r$ is randomly chosen.  Now what can you say about the value of that absolute difference for different choices of $r$?  What would you like to be able to say about it?